# Checked values not inserting to DB - PHP

Tags: php, checkbox, insert, key-value, isset

so im trying to insert the checked values from the check boxes, but isn't working. I believe my problem is they're not being set in the beginning properly. im trying to use a loop but but i believe im doing it wrong :P

my "isset":

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{

    if(empty($_POST['name'])) {die("Please enter a Your Name.");}
    if(empty($_POST['ckboxes[]'])) {die("Please check at least one box.");}
    if(empty($_POST['ddown'])) {die("Please select a value.");}
    if(empty($_POST['txtDate'])) {die("Please type in a date.");}
    if(empty($_POST['agdis'])) {die("Please agree or disagree.");}
    if(empty($_POST['yn'])) {die("Please select Yes or No.");}
```

and the insert proccess:

```
//Insert for Checkboxes//
    /////////////////////////
    $query2 = "
        INSERT INTO coffee_ckbx (
            white,
            green,
            red,
            blue
        ) VALUES (
            :white,
            :green,
            :red,
            :blue   
        )
    ";

    foreach($_POST['ckboxes'] as $check){array($check);}

    $query_params2 = array(
        ':white' => $check['1'],
        ':green' => $check['2'],
        ':red' => $check['4'],
        ':blue' => $check['5']
    );

    try
    {
        // Execute the query to create the user
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

        $stmt2 = $db->prepare($query2);
        $result2 = $stmt2->execute($query_params2);
    }
    //kept the catch out and other code due to lengthiness.
```

here's my html:

```
            <li>
            <label for='ck-boxes'>Select from the check boxes: </label>
            <input type="hidden" name="ckboxes" value="0" />
            <input type='checkbox' id='' name='ckboxes' value='white'/>
            <input type='checkbox' id='' name='ckboxes' value='green'/>
            <input type='checkbox' id='' name='ckboxes' value='red'/>
            <input type='checkbox' id='' name='ckboxes' value='blue'/>
        </li>
```

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `[]` to the end of the name, so this will tell to PHP that this is an array.

```
<input type="hidden" name="ckboxes[]" value="0" />
<input type='checkbox' id='' name='ckboxes[]' value='white'/>
<input type='checkbox' id='' name='ckboxes[]' value='green'/>
<input type='checkbox' id='' name='ckboxes[]' value='red'/>
<input type='checkbox' id='' name='ckboxes[]' value='blue'/>
```

---

Also don't quote the numbers, the things inside quotes are treated as `string`

So `$check['1']` should be `$check[1]` as example.

Comment: are the inputs in actual `form`?

Comment: yes they are in the form. Here you can see my code, maybe that will help. http://codepad.org/2sL3slm6

Comment: It's working perfectly fine for me. Just remove `isset($ckboxes)` and put `$ckboxes = $_POST['ckboxes'];` in your "`isset`".

Comment: thanks it's working now. though i didn't understand wht u meant, so not if i used the same code. my code: http://codepad.org/FaltNYjI

Comment: I do have another Q that i haven;t been able to solve. in order for any data to be inserted i HAVE to select all the check boxes, if i don't the ones i haven't checked get an 'undefined offset' error.

Comment: You can perform a bunch of ifs to check the value of `ckboxes` or you can surpress the error message by adding `@` to `$checkbox[1]`, `$checkbox[2]` & etc.